# Laravel query with RLIKE to match exact word from an string

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I've a blog type app. It has articles with tags.

Table - `tags`

```
|id|tag        |
----------------
|1 |css        |
|2 |css-library|
|3 |html       |
|4 |pre-css    |
|5 |scss    |
```

Table - `articles`

```
|id|tags                  |article|
-----------------------------------
|1 |css, html, javascript |xxxxxxx|
|2 |css-library, scss     |xxxxxxx|
|3 |html, css, bootstrap  |xxxxxxx|
```

I've the below query to find out

```
$result = DB::table('tags')
            ->leftjoin('articles', 'articles.tags', 'rlike', 'tags.tag')
            ->selectRaw('tags.tag, count(articles.id) as total')->where('articles.public', 1)
            ->groupBy('tags.tag')
            ->orderBy('total', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

When it returns the array of tags with its total use. I get wrong data. For example in case of tag `css` i'm getting `3` while i should get `2`. Query counting `css-library` as `css`.

Please help me to fix this. Thank you

Comment: why don't you use an "article_tag" table?

Comment: you mean? i dont have any other table...

Comment: I mean a manytomany relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I need to fix that query. I didnt use any Models, and i'm almost finished with the app. So now doing this via model i'll have to do many things newly

Comment: if you need to use a "like" to get something or your db (except autocomplete or few things) you have a problem on the database conception
how do you display tags of an article? you "explode" on the ","?

Comment: yeah.. using explode

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DB is mySQL, try this:

```
$result = DB::table('tags')
    ->leftjoin('articles', 'tags.tag', 'rlike', DB::raw("concat('(^|,)', articles.tags, '(,|$)')"))
    ->selectRaw('tags.tag, count(articles.id) as total')->where('articles.public', 1)
    ->groupBy('tags.tag')
    ->orderBy('total', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: it giving me bad results. not even near the one i've   :(